# Nash Equilibrium and Mixed NE Problem

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

1. Does the game have a pure Nash equilibrium?
2. Find all the mixed equilibria (note, there is at least one)

I'm having some problems solving this exercise about the game between player 1 and 2 in the picture below; from what I understood, checking the best responses of each player to each possible fixed strategy of the other player, there shouldn't be any pure NE in this game. Is this correct? How do I proceed to find the mixed equilibria?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: The problem has no dominant strategy by symmetry, and by the fact that regardless of what move 1 makes, there is no condition on which player 2 choosing $c$ is better than choosing one of $l$ or $r$. As such, we can remove the middle column. Once you do that, the mixed strategy becomes obvious by symmetry.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you removed the middle column. I understand your reasoning but I thought that, in the process of finding mixed NE, you had to find and remove all dominated columns/rows: Isn't a column/row dominated only when all the payoffs of another column/row are larger?